# infinite loop in PDA

Tags: pushdown-automata

let L be defined as $L = \{0^{2k} | k \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \{0,1\}^*$.

> language L can be described by a nondeterministic pushdown automaton P
> such that there exists at least one input for which P accepts the
> input by falling into an infinite loop

is this statement true or false? if it's true, then why?

here is what I got.
I designed a pda for a general language L using the method described in this video: https://youtu.be/ZImtQBMSW_Y?t=529 (as I know, posting picture is not allowed in problem. so I provided a link to the video I used to draw the PDA)

but I couldn't go further. can you guys help me please?